# How can I improve my formal definitions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, definitions, mathematical-writing, peer-review

I am a Software Architect and not very familiarized with standard notation in mathematics. Nonetheless, I would like to write a paper explaining a normalization of a computing model for expert systems. It has a very deep background on geometry, logic and group theory, so I have to define some [new] unusual mathematical objects, and in order to get it accepted by the reader (some of them scientists of different disciplines) I would like to be as clear and correct as possible. How can I improve these definitions? Does anyone or any company offer this "help" as a service?

I have about 20 definitions like the following (only for instance) to be improved.

> The $m$-**crown** of a set $S$, denoted by $S^m$, is the family of sets of every subset of its index set of cardinality $m$ not containing its index, such that
>
> $$\forall(X_i \in S^m : i \in S) \rightarrow X_i = \{ x \subset S :(i\notin x 
> \land|x|=m) \}$$

(Note: I am sure that it is a correct definition but may be not easy to understand with a not very standarized notation)

Comment: I have created the chat room "Pioneers" ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98162/pioneers ) to discuss this type of "innovations"; everyone is welcome;)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I don't know about a definition-checking service, but I can give some general advice which I think will help.

Let me begin by rewriting your definition (hopefully correctly!):

> Suppose I have a set $S$ and a natural number $m$. For $i\in S$, let $$X_i=\{a\subseteq S: \vert a\vert=m\mbox{ and }i\not\in a\}.$$ We then let the $m$-crown of $S$ be the indexed set (with indexing set $S$ itself) $$(X_i)_{i\in S}.$$ For example, if $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $m=2$ then e.g. $$X_2=\{\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ and the whole $m$-crown of $S$ is $$($$ $$X_1=\{\{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ $$X_2=\{\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ $$X_3=\{\{1,2\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\}\},$$ $$X_4=\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\}$$ $$).$$

Now, what's behind this?

---

Let's start with what I *have* done.

**First, AND MOST IMPORTANTLY, I've broken the definition into separate pieces and worked from the inside out.** My version of the definition *ends* by introducing the $m$-crown, and *starts* by introducing the much simpler $X_i$s. Moreover, my version breaks into multiple separate sentences. Think of this all as a kind of cognitive piton: it lets the reader digest the definition in discrete steps, without ever having to be kept guessing what things mean. It also helps prevent errors on your end, by making you think carefully about what exactly is going on at each step along the way - when you write an "outside-in" definition, it's easy to experience a kind of "precision fatigue" and wind up finishing with something unclear or garbled. Finally, it winds up helping you use natural language in a precise way, for the same reason.

**Second, I've provided nontrivial explicit examples of everything.** Moreover, I haven't tried to mix notations to be more efficient - the only thing I've done is throw in some spacing for readability *(which is actually quite useful in some situations, and sets-of-sets is one of those since the curly braces can blur together)*. This helps the reader both understand your definition and repair it if you have made any errors.

Besides all that, examples also provide a more high-level kind of cognitive piton: in the course of a slew of definitions, they help me keep straight what each thing is and how the various things differ from each other. Really, you should *always* give examples of *everything*.

---

Now let me point out two things I *haven't* done.

**First, I avoided using too many symbols.** In particular I avoided quantifiers. There's a positive and a negative aspect to this. The positive aspect is that *precise natural language* is easier to read than symbolic expressions; it's almost always better to focus on making your explanation precise than using symbols to shorten everything (and the "piton" stuff above is a big help here).

The negative aspect is that unless one has some experience with the relevant formalism, it's easy to misuse - and this is exceptionally true of quantifiers for whatever reason. In the case of your definition, when blindly rendered into English your expression $$\forall(X_i \in S^m : i \in S) \rightarrow X_i = \{ x \subset S :(i\notin x 
\land|x|=m) \} $$ translates to

- "If for all *[missing bound variable]*, $X_i$ is in $S^m$ *[grammatically incorrect symbol - maybe "such that"?]* $i$ in $S$, then $X_i$ is the set of subsets of $S$ of size $m$ not containing $i$."

The second half of that is what you want, but the first half is thoroughly garbled. Indeed, my first guess at rewriting this would be

- "If $X_i$ is in $S^m$ for every $i\in S$, then *[rest]*,"

which is very much not what you want. And reading not being much easier than writing, even if you'd gotten the symbols right your readers might still have trouble following the definition.

**Second, I didn't put motivation inside the definition proper.** This isn't something you did either, but it is a common issue *(and like everything else makes it much easier to mess up natural-language definitions)* so it's worth mentioning here. You should definitely include motivation, but put it before or after the definition (or both); keep the definition itself nice and clean.

Here's an example of the sort of thing I'm railing against:

> Let FOO be the tensor product of BLAH, which by Theorem 11.36 characterizes the FLEEN completely, with (in order to de-VORP the resulting algebra) BLEELG.

It would be much better to write this as:

> Let FOO = BLAH $\otimes$ BLEELG.
>
> Remember that BLAH completely characterizes the FLEEN (Thm. 11.36); meanwhile, bringing BLEELG prevents VORPiness.

Note that I've also broken the motivation itself into separate pieces: why the BLAH?, and why the BLEELG?, are separate issues and I've treated them as such.

---

**Now it's important to note that these rules don't always have to be followed. But I think one should follow them very closely if one isn't already rather experienced with this sort of writing, especially if the intended readership isn't necessarily either.**

Comment: OP writes "family" rather than "set". Therefore, I would write: We then let the $m$-crown of $S$ be the family $$(X_i: i\in S).$$ For example, if $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $m=2$ then e.g. $$X_2=\{\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ and the whole $m$-crown of $S$ is $$($$ $$(1)\ \{\{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ $$(2)\ \{\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,4\}\},$$ $$(3)\ \{\{1,2\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\}\},$$ $$(4)\ \{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\}$$ $$).$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber It sounds very reasonable, I'm glad to read you. However, I feel that it is not exactly the same definition, it seems not to be an indexed family. Furthermore, it seems that each definition is going to be very extensive including motivation. I usually present some definitions to "build" another bigger showing the motivation of them togother. I don't know it can be weak syllogism.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi that was I would to say in the previous comment.

Comment: @IzarUrdin: Ok, Noah understood you better than me. Note that if you like Noah's answer (I do!), you can *accept* it.

Comment: One question ... you use "and" insteed of "$\land$" ??

Comment: @IzarUrdin Yes - **symbols don't inherently add clarity**. Don't use them just because you can; a clear, precise natural language definition is (in almost every case) optimal. Basically, which is generally more readable: $$\{x: A\wedge B\}$$ or $$\{x: A\mbox{ and }B\}?$$ When the conditions $A$ and $B$ are at all complicated, it's usually the latter.

Comment: @IzarUrdin I've modified my answer to better capture your definition.  Re: "it seems that each definition is going to be very extensive including motivation," that may be unavoidable - but the advice I gave still applies.

Comment: That´s incredible and a good news ! When I was a student of Computer Since (25 years ago) teachers forced us to use symbols instead of words. Things are going better ;)

Comment: @Izar Urdin: *When I was a student of Computer Since (25 years ago) teachers forced us to use symbols instead of words.* --- Nearly 50 years ago (1970), [Paul Halmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Halmos) wrote ["The best notation is no notation; whenever it is possible to avoid the use of a complicated alphabetic apparatus, avoid it."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+best+notation+is+no+notation%3B+whenever+it+is+possible+to+avoid%22).

Comment: This is truly fantastic advice, and should be a standard reference for anyone writing mathematics.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: I don't agree with that at all. In my opinion and experience, only students who can completely grasp the formal (first-order) definition of limits and the induction schema can truly understand them. I do think that it is convenient to use natural language when there is low logical complexity, but I find it unwise to suggest avoiding symbols in situations of high logical complexity. After all, symbols **were designed** to attain precision, whereas natural language cannot always do it. People today happily use symbols like $+,−,×,÷,^2$. Imagine eschewing them for words!

Comment: Mathematical symbols are part of the mathematical language that develops over time. In the past, we had less symbols and hence much less **ability** to handle complicated mathematics. Before the rudiments of first-order logic were introduced, many mathematicians employed dubious or even incorrect reasoning due to unclear quantifier order. Now we have the ability to handle arbitrarily complicated mathematics, thanks to formalization over FOL. Just try doing measure theory or higher set theory while avoiding symbols!

Comment: That said, we should employ the **cleanest** presentation possible, and sometimes this does mean less symbols. For example, "finite subsets of $S$" is much better than "$\{ T : T⊆S ∧ \#(T) < ω \}$", and expanding the definition of cardinality would make it even worse.

Comment: @user21820 The reason "finite subsets of S" is clearer is primarily because of the increased clarity associated with the use of the definition "finite". It would be more difficult to correctly render $\{T:T\subseteq S\land \#(T\setminus\{3\})<5\}$; if you attempt to use english locutions to avoid introducing the variable $T$ you end up with something like "the set of subsets of $S$ such that removing $\{3\}$ results in a set with cardinality less than $5$" so clearly the word "finite" was pulling a lot of weight.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Yes, commonly used notions should be packaged into definitions. But also note that it's not just definitions that help; the natural language grammar is convenient for this particular phrase. More generally, if we have "[adj] [adj] ... [noun]" where each [adj] is a single word, then it is almost always better to use that than to use a formal logical conjunction. Anyway, your example can be phrased cleanly as "subsets of $S$ with less than $5$ elements different from $3$".

Comment: Another consideration is that some definitions have no symbolic analogue, and so you will want to use them in "text mode" when possible. For example, while "subset" has the associated notation $\subseteq$, "finite" has no analogue, so it should be used in an english phrase when possible (i.e. "finite subsets of $S$"), or in embedded text as a last resort (i.e. $\{T:T\subseteq S\wedge T\mbox{ is finite}\}$). Conversely, some symbols like $+$ or ${}^2$ are best rendered as symbols because the english locutions are more cumbersome. ...

Comment: ... For me, this is usually what determines which parts of a statement to render in english and which parts to render in symbols.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: No. It is well-established in mathematical logic (proof theory, reverse mathematics, set theory) that $[S]^{<κ}$ denotes the set of subsets of $S$ of cardinality less than $κ$, and $[S]^κ$ denotes the set of subsets of size $κ$. And you will almost surely see this notation in infinitary combinatorics. At different levels in your mathematical learning, different notations will be more suitable for your mental processing. There is no single notational convention that is best for all at the same time.

Comment: @user21820 Since $[S]^{<\omega}$ isn't very known outside of set theory, I'd say Mario's point is meaningfully correct. Regardless, none of this is in tension the point: when one should use symbols is determined in large part by readability, which in turn is highly context-dependent. And while there are certainly situations where the symbolism is crucial, either as a language (like computer-verified proofs) or an object of study in and of itself (in logic), readability is indeed almost always the dominating concern.

Comment: Anyways, I'm going to tentatively suggest a moratorium on further comments (if only because I keep getting pinged!).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Sure; I agree with your remarks. My initial comment was just in reaction to Dave's comment that implicitly suggested that the best was **no** symbolic notation at all even for students, and that would be a severe pedagogical mistake, as my teaching experience attests. Thanks for putting up with the pinging! =)

Comment: @NoahSchweber and company, all of you are very kind and I am very satisfied with your comments and advicing. I know the comments are not for this proposal, but I don't know how to thank you all this awsome response. Sincerely, thankyou very much.

Comment: I don't think adding an example contributes anything to the definition. It's merely an unwinding of the definition (as opposed to, e.g., adding to the definition of a group examples "in the wild" like $\mathbb{Z}_n, GL_n(k)$, etc.), and the reader should be able to do that for him- or herself.

Comment: This is incredibly lovely and I'm so glad you took the time to write it. One of the biggest barriers I find in my undergraduate math majors with their first proof-based course is the apparent belief that "writing math" must be all symbols and not mostly sentences.